# What is the best way to grab first URL segment from Vue.js hash mode?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have this URL generated by my vue.js app

```
http://localhost:8080/#/url-groups
```

I need to access `url-groups`

I've tried

```
const firstSegment = new URL(window.location.href).pathname.split('/#/')
```

I kept getting '/'

---

I've also tried :

```
const firstSegment = new URL(window.location.href).pathname.split('#'); console.log(firstSegment);
VM21687:1 ['/']


const firstSegment = new URL(window.location.href).pathname.split('/#/'); console.log(firstSegment);
VM21719:1 ['/']


const firstSegment = new URL(window.location.href).pathname.split('/'); console.log(firstSegment);
VM21751:1 (2) ['', '']
```

Can someone pls correct me ?

Answer (score 2):

Try out to get the hash segment then split using `/` as separator finally get the element of the splitted array :

```js
const [,secondSegment] = new URL(window.location.href).hash.split('/')
```

or

```js
const segment= new URL(window.location.href).hash.replace('#/','')
```

Comment: `[,` what is this ? typo ?

Comment: Do you know another way to grab first URL ?

Comment: not a typo, `[,element]` means to destruct an array into two items

Comment: you could try also `const secondSegment = new URL(window.location.href).hash.replace('#/','')`

Comment: I know you kept doing secondSegment, but is it in addition to what I have of firstSegment ? or this is a replace of what I have of firstSegment ?

Comment: just a name you could name it `const segment = ....`

Comment: I got what I am looking for while doing this `window.location.href.split('/')[4]`

Comment: May I know why we need to use new URL() instead of just call `window.location.href` directly ?

Comment: the URL object gives more details than just the href string, but in your case I think `window.location.href` is sufficient

Answer (score 0):

In case that's still relevant - you can use `vue-router`.
Assuming you are using Vue 3 or the composition API, it would look like this:

```
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';

const route = useRoute();
const firstSegment = route.path;
```